# Query nested linked lists

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linked-list, nested

I'm trying to query a nested linked list where result is the product of a child value multiplied by values in the parent list, and then the result is added.

This code works:

```
var X = (from B in Main.Globals.BookLL
                    from G in B.GreeksLL
                    where B.DealNo == 1 && B.Strategy == "Condor" &&
                    G.BookOrComp == "Book" && G.GreekType == "Delta"
                    select new
                    {
                        Total = G.Data[3] * B.BookPosn * B.FxRate
                    }).Sum(s=>s.Total);
```

...but I'd prefer to use lambda. This code below gives the compile error shown as a comment at the end of the line.

```
double Z = Globals.BookLL.Where(B => B.DealNo == 1 && B.Strategy == "Condor").
            SelectMany(G => G.GreeksLL).
            Where(G => G.BookOrComp == "Book" && G.GreekType == "Delta").
            Select(G => new { Total = G.Data[3] * B.BookPosn*B.FxRate }).           // Compile error "B does not exist in the current context"
            Sum();
```

I don't know how to do this, please take a look and correct the query? Thanks.

Comment: _"This code doesn't work"_ - is not helpful.

Comment: @MickyD read the `// B does not exist in the current context` in the code.

Comment: I get the compile error shown as a comment in the code. Ok I'll edit the question!

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I'm aware.  A well written question shouldn't force you to read comments in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
double Z = Globals.BookLL.Where(B => B.DealNo == 1 && B.Strategy == "Condor").
           SelectMany(par => par.GreeksLL, (parent, child) => new { G = child, B = parent }).
           Where(both => both.G.BookOrComp == "Book" && both.G.GreekType == "Delta").
           Select(both => new { Total = both.G.Data[3] * both.B.BookPosn*both.B.FxRate }).
           Sum(x => x.Total);
```

My naming is a bit weird, but I hope you get the idea, basically you 'abandoned' B when you did `SelectMany()`, and this should be the way.

It is untested, so let me know if it works.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx) for `SelectMany()` with *results selector function*.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I appreciate the help. I'll take a look at the link to get upskilled.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to filter the GreekLL inside the SelectMany using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631.aspx) overload, and then use [Sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734(v=vs.110).aspx) extension:

```
double z = Main.Globals.BookLL.Where(book => book.DealNo == 1 && book.Strategy == "Condor")
           .SelectMany(book => book.GreeksLL.Where(greek => greek.BookOrComp == "Book" && greek.GreekType == "Delta")
               ,(book, greek) => new { Greek = greek, Book = book })
           .Sum(greekAndBook => greekAndBook.Book.BookPosn *  greekAndBook.Book.Fxrate * greekAndBook.Greek.Data[3]);
```

Comment: thanks, but I get a compile error saying the name ``'Sum' does not exist in the current context``

Comment: @Zeus  I confused regular brackets with curly brackets, fixed it, can you try it again?

Comment: That's working now! Thanks for your effort and another method.